# Troubleshooting "Waiting on Condition"

Tags: java, tomcat, coldfusion, stack-trace, coldfusion-11

I'm trying to track down some performance issues we are experiencing intermittently after upgrading from ColdFusion 9 to 11.  JVM version went from 1.6/1.7 to 1.8(currently U40)

Server runs fine for around a week and then goes through periods of performance degradation until re-start. These periods last 30 seconds to a minute and occur every few minutes.  Duration extends and time-in-between reduces as time goes on.  Upon re-start performance returns to normal

Stack traces taken at the time of performance degradation indicate a lot of threads "Waiting on Condition", however I cannot see the condition.  Usually, I would expect to see the reason the thread is waiting on the top of the stack trace.

In this case, we do not.

Looking @ GC logs, this does not appear to be related to STW GC collections. (they are approx every 30 mins to every hour)

Stack traces taken 2 seconds part show the threads are moving to different parts of code, only to hit up against the "Waiting for Condition" again. In fact, the same request (thread) can move Waiting for Condition through it's observable life.

If I throw significant load at the server, when it is running fine then I don't see any "Waiting for Condition" in worker threads.

Here is an example stack trace.

> "ajp-bio-8014-exec-281" #70085 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000074c73000 nid=0x21b0 waiting on condition [0x00000000487cb000]
>      java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
>       at cfCPStandard2ecfc1872558760$funcGETMAINCONTENTHEADER.runFunction(D:\JO3\jobOffice\sys\jo\core\de\templates\cp\CPStandard.cfc)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:487)
>       at coldfusion.filter.SilentFilter.invoke(SilentFilter.java:47)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:420)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:383)
>       at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:95)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:334)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:231)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(CfJspPage.java:2845)
>       at cfCPStandard2ecfc1872558760$funcLOADPAGEHEADER.runFunction(D:\JO3\jobOffice\sys\jo\core\de\templates\cp\CPStandard.cfc:54)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:487)
>       at coldfusion.filter.SilentFilter.invoke(SilentFilter.java:47)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:420)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:383)
>       at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:95)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:334)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:231)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:643)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:432)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:402)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2483)
>       at cfDisplayEngine2ecfc1810328208$funcPOSTPROCESS.runFunction(D:\JO3\jobOffice\sys\jo\core\m2plugin\DisplayEngine.cfc:52)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:487)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:420)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:383)
>       at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:95)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:334)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:231)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:643)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:432)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:402)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2483)
>       at cfPluginManager2ecfc1495337580$funcPOSTPROCESS.runFunction(D:\JO3\jobOffice\MachII\framework\PluginManager.cfc:591)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:487)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:420)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:383)
>       at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:95)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:334)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:231)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:643)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:432)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:402)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2483)
>       at cfRequestHandler2ecfc1676430457$funcPROCESSEVENTS.runFunction(D:\JO3\jobOffice\MachII\framework\RequestHandler.cfc:308)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:487)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:420)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:383)
>       at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:95)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:334)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:231)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(CfJspPage.java:2845)
>       at cfRequestHandler2ecfc1676430457$funcHANDLEREQUEST.runFunction(D:\JO3\jobOffice\MachII\framework\RequestHandler.cfc:208)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:487)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:420)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:383)
>       at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:95)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:334)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:231)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:643)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:432)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:402)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2483)
>       at cfmach2dii2ecfc1440816939$funcHANDLEREQUEST.runFunction(D:\JO3\jobOffice\MachII\mach-ii.cfc:210)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:487)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:420)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:383)
>       at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:95)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:334)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:231)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(CfJspPage.java:2845)
>       at cfmach2dii2ecfc1440816939$funcONREQUESTSTART.runFunction(D:\JO3\jobOffice\MachII\mach-ii.cfc:121)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:487)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:420)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:383)
>       at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:95)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:334)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:231)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(CfJspPage.java:2845)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2503)
>       at cfApplication2ecfc1530162842$funcONREQUESTSTART.runFunction(D:\JO3\wwwroot\Application.cfc:233)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:487)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:420)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:383)
>       at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:95)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:334)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:231)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:643)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:432)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:402)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.invoke(AppEventInvoker.java:108)
>       at coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.onRequestStart(AppEventInvoker.java:279)
>       at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:455)
>       at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
>       at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:142)
>       at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:94)
>       at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
>       at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
>       at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:58)
>       at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
>       at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
>       at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62)
>       at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:219)
>       at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
>       at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor87.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filterchain.WrappedFilterChain.doFilter(WrappedFilterChain.java:97)
>       at com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filter.FusionReactorRequestHandler.doNext(FusionReactorRequestHandler.java:472)
>       at com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filter.FusionReactorRequestHandler.doHttpServletRequest(FusionReactorRequestHandler.java:312)
>       at com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filter.FusionReactorRequestHandler.doFusionRequest(FusionReactorRequestHandler.java:192)
>       at com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filter.FusionReactorRequestHandler.handle(FusionReactorRequestHandler.java:507)
>       at com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filter.FusionReactorCoreFilter.doFilter(FusionReactorCoreFilter.java:36)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor72.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filterchain.WrappedFilterChain.doFilter(WrappedFilterChain.java:79)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor59.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at com.intergral.fusionreactor.agent.filter.FusionReactorStaticFilter.doFilter(FusionReactorStaticFilter.java:53)
>       at com.intergral.fusionreactor.agent.pointcuts.NewFilterChainPointCut$1.invoke(NewFilterChainPointCut.java:41)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:422)
>       at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:199)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
>       - locked <0x000000051d486850> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

My question is: how do I track down what [0x00000000487cb000] is? It seems like it's coming from withing the JVM itself. (ie, not a user-code generated wait).

Comment: What's the code in the `getMainContentHeader()` function in CPStandard.cfc? And in any other methods it happens to call. Sounds like you've got a `<cflock>` deadlock or something.

Comment: Nothing remarkable in getMainContentHeader, and in the second thread dump (2 seconds later) it has moved on to anther method which is also Waiting on Condition, with no indication of what the resource is that it is waiting for. You can see the same thread move from stack-trace to stack-trace (2 seconds part), in and out of different code very slowly but always "Waiting on Condition". Not of these areas of thread dumps have anything in common - infact, some are "Waiting for Condition" inside of FusionReactor java code.  Feels like we are running out of some resource, not sure what though.